# How to split a 2-digit number from a textbox and store the digits in labels

Tags: vb.net, string

How do I split a 2-digit number from a textbox and put the first digit in one label and the second digit in another label when a button is clicked?

Comment: I'm sorry but that doesn't look like a question to me, and if it is I don't understand it. Suggest you rewrite it with code for us to go on and a proper question.

Comment: how do you write it in visual basic code, to get the digits to seperate when plugged into a text box into two different labels

Answer (score 1):

This assume there is one textbox (TextBox1) , two labels (Label1, Label2) and a button (Button1) on the form.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Label1.Text = "First digit:" & TextBox1.Text.Substring(0, 1)
    Label2.Text = "Second digit:" & TextBox1.Text.Substring(1, 1)
End Sub
```

Of course you should test for the length and if its really a number entered before doing this, so adding some checking would be a good practice:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If Not IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) Then
            MsgBox("You have to enter a number between 10 and 99 in the textbox.", MsgBoxStyle.Information Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Not a number")
        ElseIf TextBox1.Text.Length <> 2 Then
            MsgBox("You have to enter a 2 digit number in the textbox.", MsgBoxStyle.Information Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Not a 2 digit number")
        Else
            Label1.Text = "First digit:" & TextBox1.Text.Substring(0, 1)
            Label2.Text = "Second digit:" & TextBox1.Text.Substring(1, 1)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to type a number into a text box, click a button, and have the text box display the number with the digits separated by a space.

```
Dim sNum As String
sNum = tbNum.Value 'assuming tbNum is the name of the textbox control
Dim sNewNum As String
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To Len( sNum )
    sNewNum = Mid( sNum, i, 1 )
    If i < Len( sNum ) Then sNewNum = sNewNum & " " 
Next
tbNum.Value = sNewNum
```

Now that hasn't been tested (straight from brain to keyboard) but that's the basic idea, treating the number as a string of characters.